# SSIS Lookup Expression for Formatting a Date in Dynamic SQL

Tags: ssis, db2, lookup

I have a variable in my SSIS package.

```
@LastFridayDateTime = Datetime Datatype = DATEADD("hh",17,(DT_DBTIMESTAMP) (   (DT_STR,30,1252) (DT_DBDATE) (DATEADD("dd", -1 - (DATEPART("dw", getdate()) % 7), getdate()) ) ) )
```

This gives me a value = 6/14/2019 5:00:00 PM

Now I am trying to use dynamic Select query for my SSIS lookup expression.
For that I am in the control flow, click on my Data Flow Task--> Properties --> Expression --> [Lookup].sqlcommand and tying my Select query.

```
"SELECT No, Date_tran
FROM  TABLE
WHERE Date_tran  >= " + (DT_STR,20,1252) @[User::LastFridayDateTime]
```

Which Evaluates to

```
SELECT No, Date_tran
FROM  TABLE
WHERE Date_tran  >= 6/14/2019 5:00:00 PM
```

And Hence its not working due to 5:00:00 PM I guess.
My question is,
I want this Date to be in this format '6/14/2019 5:00:00'  rather than 6/14/2019 5:00:00 PM
So that the query can compile and execute.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easiest to just change `(DT_STR,20,1252)` to `(DT_STR,18,1252)`?

Comment: Thanks but I tried that already and not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to wrap single quotes around the datetime value in your expression:

```
"SELECT No, Date_tran
FROM  TABLE
WHERE Date_tran  >= '" + (DT_STR,20,1252)@[User::LastFridayDateTime] + "'"
```

**EDIT:** Sure enough, you need to first cast your `datetime` variable to a `DT_DBTIMESTAMP` before you cast it again to a string. Have I mentioned how much I love the 67 different sets of SSIS datatypes?

This should work, though, as ridiculous as it seems:

```
"SELECT No, Date_tran
FROM  TABLE
WHERE Date_tran  >= '" + (DT_STR,20, 1252)(DT_DBTIMESTAMP) @[User::LastFridayDateTime] + "'"
```

Comment: Thanks Eric.I added that quote as u suggested but still its putting PM at end. Its only happening when I use it this way in dynamic SQL. This variable works fine if I directly call it in OLE DB Source as a parameter. There it doesnt include PM.

Comment: it worked. Thanks Eric. I am glad u love those 67 datatypes. I am new to it and would love to learn them. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, @nick, glad it helped. If you could take a second to click the little gray check box to the left to accept the answer, I'd be most appreciative!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command:

```
"SELECT No, Date_tran
FROM  TABLE
WHERE Date_tran  >= CONVERT(DATETIME,'" + (DT_STR,20,1252) @[User::LastFridayDateTime]  + "',102)"
```

You can refer to the following article to get the relevant format number if `102` didn't work:

- [Date and Time Conversions Using SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/)

OR

```
"SELECT No, Date_tran
FROM  TABLE
WHERE Date_tran  >= CAST('" + (DT_STR,20,1252) @[User::LastFridayDateTime]  + "' AS DATETIME)"
```

Comment: Thanks Hadi but Eric's Sol below works. With your solution its adds  >= CAST('6/14/2019 5:00:00 PM' AS DATETIME) at the end of my SQL Select query that I run agaisnt DB2 database and gives some error. Thanks for the reply though. it may work in sqL server.

Comment: @nick OK.. but you didn't mentioned that you are using DB2

Comment: my bad Hadi. I just missed that in rush. Sorry